# Text folding in matlab is not working

Tags: matlab, folding

Text folding is not working in my matlab 2013. I enabled everything in preferences Editor/Debugger, but still no luck. Below is an example of what I am trying to fold.

```
test = 5;

%%
t =7;

%%
```

Answer (score 3):

What did you enable in the preferences? In R2013a you should go to *Preferences > Editor/Debugger > Code Folding* and click the *Enable* checkbox for *Sections* that is off by default. Then click *Apply* or *OK*. Here's an annotated screen capture of Code Folding pane of my preferences:

[image]

You should see a little minus toggle button appear to the left of the first `%%` instance in your example:

[image]

Clicking the toggle button will fold the section of code. You will also find other options and keyboard shortcuts under the contextual menu by right-clicking or control-clicking.

Comment: Thank you, horchler! Enable code folding was already checked by default. But checking Sections fixed my problem. I guess I was confused about it because matlab refered to it as cells.